# How to call a function

Tags: c#, function, encryption

This one function is current class. How Can I call it?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //------
      //------

      String r = EncryptText<Cryptography.Aes>(myTextStringToEncode);
    }
      private string EncryptText<TSymmetricAlgorithm>(string input) where TSymmetricAlgorithm : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
        {
            var pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MY560Secratekey38433661283912");
            using (TSymmetricAlgorithm sa = new TSymmetricAlgorithm())
            {
                ICryptoTransform saEnc = sa.CreateEncryptor(pwdBytes, pwdBytes);

                var encBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

                var resultBytes = saEnc.TransformFinalBlock(encBytes, 0, encBytes.Length);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(resultBytes);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EncryptText<System.Security.Cryptography.Aes>("hello world")`

for example?!

see inheritance hierarchy @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.aspx

Comment: It gives Error 'System.Security.Cryptography.Aes' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TSymmetricAlgorithm' in the generic type or method

Comment: ah!
SRY!
try `System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged` vor example
check the given inheritance hierarchy to choose the correct algorithm...
it's a generic method which constructs a new object of the chosen SymmetricAlgorithm-Class to encrypt the things.

Comment: It is in a project which is undocumented and I have to make some changes. I am not familiar with Lambda expressions..

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = EncryptText<MySymmetricAlgorithm>("my input");
```

I'd suggest you to think of a slightly different approach too:

```
string EncryptText(SymmetricAlgorithm algo, string input);
```

The drawback is that consumer have to worry about creating instances of the algorithm. You can use implementations without no-param constructors though. Moreover, you could re-use instances too.

It's best to decide what fits best into your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = this.EncryptText<MySymmetricAlgorith>("blup");
```